# Finding another thread's Thread Information Block

Tags: windows, multithreading, seh

Is there a way to find the Thread Information Block (TIB) of another thread running in your process?

I need to construct an exception handler for another thread but I can't do it in the thread itself. Therefore I need to find it's TIB and construct it from inside another thread. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can alter the TIB of any thread... probably not even in Kernel mode.

Comment: Of course you can, it's just an in-memory data structure. It's a terrible idea to do so, but it's not magic - it's in usermode.

Comment: @Paul Betts, Would you also have an idea on how to do it?

Comment: @Paul, you can always alter whatever you wish if you really want to, but that's not to say that it's a good idea.  I was only saying it from the POV that it's generally not a good idea to fiddle with it.

Comment: I agree with floyd73's answer: you may use `GetThreadContext` to obtain the `FS` selector and get the TIB. However I don't fully understand what you mean by "constructing an exception handler". Do you mean you want to explicitly add a SEH exception registration **record** to the chain with your handler? Note that AFAIK SEH registration records must come in descending memory order (this is a OS protection against memory corruption). Normally there's no problems since such records are allocated on the stack, but there may be a problem with your approach

Comment: Anyway, can you please add more info about your "handler"? What are you trying to achieve? Should it only perform a cleanup in case of the unwinding, or it may also "Handle" the exception (i.e. return `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER` and pass control to some address)?

Comment: By constructing another exception handler, I mean adding another record to the exception chain, however, in the meantime I've found out that the fs register holds (and points to) the exact same location on both threads, I think it has something to do with the Linear address of the thread-local storage array, which (as I understand it) is some sort of reallocation table for all the memory addresses the thread uses, I've know idea how to walk it though. Do you know a way to find the TIB of the other thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the address of the TIB directly from the FS register (check http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S2CE.aspx). 
So to get the TIB for another thread maybe can use GetThreadContext() to get the value of FS and therefore the address of the TIB? (just a guess, I didn't try this!)

Comment: I'll try this, it seems to be possible to retrieve the FS register of another thread using this API:                                                            DWORD SegGs;
DWORD SegFs;
DWORD SegEs;

Answer (score 1):

```
void PrintTibAddress(DWORD thread_id) {
  HANDLE thread_handle = OpenThread(THREAD_GET_CONTEXT | THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, thread_id);
  if (thread_handle == NULL) return;

  SuspendThread(thread_handle);

  CONTEXT context;
  context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_SEGMENTS;
  if (!GetThreadContext(thread_handle, &context)) {
    CloseHandle(thread_handle);
    return;
  }

  LDT_ENTRY ldtSel;
  if (!GetThreadSelectorEntry(thread_handle, context.SegFs, &ldtSel)) return;

  ResumeThread(thread_handle);

  DWORD fs_base = (ldtSel.HighWord.Bits.BaseHi << 24 ) | ( ldtSel.HighWord.Bits.BaseMid << 16 ) | ( ldtSel.BaseLow );
  fwprintf(stdout, L"[i] FS:[0] (TIB) is @ 0x%08X\n", fs_base);
}
```

References:

http://recxltd.blogspot.de/2012/02/from-archives-printing-seh-chain-from.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx

Complete sample program: http://pastebin.com/gSTcPz1y

Answer (score 0):

You can get the TIB of a thread, but altering it I doubt very much you can do.

As correctly pointed out by Paul, this only gets the TIB for the thread it's used it, so I suggest calling it in the thread from which you need this data and then moving it to the thread where you need to use it.

To get it you can use something like this, described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block):

```
// Microsoft C
void *getTib()
{
    void *pTib;
    __asm {
        mov EAX, FS:[0x18]
        mov [pTib], EAX
    }
    return pTib;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not work, but try [queueing a user-mode APC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681951%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the target thread which sets up your exception handler.